# Kerberos authentication for delegation in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, kerberos

I'm trying to create a .net web page that uses UserPrinciple.Current to get details of the currently logged in user, and allow them to change their Active Directory password.

After a fair bit of head-bashing, I got it working (yay!).  My only issue is that I want it working on our intranet site (http://intranet) but it only seems to work if I specify the fully qualified domain name (http://intranet.mydomain.co.uk).

Looking at this page ([How to configure an ASP.NET application for a delegation scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572)) the troubleshooting section at the bottom of the 'Summary' section seems to contain two conflicting pieces of advice:

> 3.For Kerberos to work correctly, you must use fully qualified domain names (FQDN) for all the communication.
>
> 5.If the Web server uses a fully qualified domain name, you must add the site is added to the list of intranet sites in Internet Explorer.

Note that item 5 starts with **IF** - suggesting that it doesn't **HAVE** to do so.  But Item 3 states that a FQDN is necessary.

So the question is simple: can I set up delegation through IIS 7 without using a FQDN host name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **both** otherwise it won't work for a good reason and IE will fallback to NTLM. Jus a side-note, it is really pointless to write a webapp where a user can change his AD password. This should be done through the Windows change password dialog and not some third party tool.

Comment: It's only pointless if your users have access to the Windows change password dialog box.  If they are mobile users using mobile devices then (at least with the setup that we have) they don't have that, so to change their password they either need a webapp that they can access remotely, or they have to make a special trip into the office.  You've still answered my question though, in that I must use the FQDN.

Comment: I hate computers.  I just went back to my 'change password' web page, and it is now working correctly **without** using FQDN. I swear it wasn't working when I left it at way-past-hometime on Friday evening!  So the answer to my question seems to be: Yes, you can have delegation without an FQDN, as long as it's not friday evening...

Comment: How can this work? Kerberos should fail. Please inspect the HTTP traffic with Wireshark and report if you can. I'd be more than happy to understand what's happening.

Comment: Ok, I'm not an expert with Wireshark, but having checked the traffic it is definitely passing a Kerberos ticket (which it had to be doing for the AD Change Password request to work).  The ticket **DOES** contains the FQDN of the intranet site, even though I didn't specify it in the URL, which explains why it is working, even if it doesn't explain how the FQDN got there.  I guess that somewhere along the line, something recognises that 'intranet' actually translates to 'intranet.mydomain.co.uk' - maybe from the DNS record?

Comment: Yes, it is probably DNS. It works like this: GSS-API/SSPI resolves the hostname to the IP address and then reverse-resolves to a hostname. This is how the SPN is built. This has probably been in your case.